# Why do I need to specify ":80" when using "apt-key adv"?

Tags: keyrings

How come

```
apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 0xcbcb082a1bb943db
```

would fail but

```
apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xcbcb082a1bb943db
```

would not?

How do I check what is being blocked?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [OpenPGP HTTP Key Protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-shaw-openpgp-hkp-00) operates, by default, [on port 11371](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?search=hkp).

The Ubuntu Keyserver is run on port 80 (by default, used by www-http) to reduce problems that can be caused by firewalls.  So you need the port and protocol to make sure that GPG (which is running the request behind-the-scenes) knows exactly where to go to get the key.

Your first example is equivalent to:

```
apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371 0xcbcb082a1bb943db
```

Since you need to specify `:80` when using `apt-key adv`, your network administrator or ISP has blocked port 11371.

Comment: Ubuntu's keyserver listens on port 80 so that you don't have any problem if your ISP/proxy/firewall blocks some ports.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini (and Cliff) But it also works/listens on 11371.